# Workflow Publishing : (-1, -1) Compilation failed. Could not find file 'C:\Users\<domain>\AppData\Local\Temp\z1pwejy2.dll'.)

Tags: sharepoint-server, designer-workflow

Previously we had a one single Application Server and a database server. We recently added a new server in our SharePoint Farm to handle the Search Service Application Load. The workflow and Web Foundation services are turned off from the second server. All of sudden we getting the following error while publishing the workflow :

> (-1, -1) Compilation failed. Could not find file 'C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\z1pwejy2.dll'.)

The name of the dll changes with every publish attempt. However, an IISreset seems to solve the issue but temporarily. The issue arises again after a while.

Any idea why this happens ?

Answer (score 0):

During the workflow publishing phase, SharePoint will create couple of temporary files under the temp folder (of the app pool service account). As part of clean-up process w3wp process will delete this files later.

Sometimes, instead of deleting content inside temp folder w3wp process deletes the temp folder. Because of which workflow publishing fails with “Could not find a part of the path”

**How to work around this issue?**

Create a text file and provide read only access to file. This will stop process from deleting temp folder.

Navigate to C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp on both the server (WFE1 and WFE2)

Create a text file inside the temp folder and in the properties check read-only option.

Reset iis /noforce

Comment: I am not getting this "Could not find a part of the path" error. I am getting "Could not find File" problem.